# word game advice

Tags: xna

My background is as a linguist, and so for new years decide to learn computer language, c#, out of interest and so that I can make small word games for my children and students. 
I have started to look at word games and have been reading about using char types and char arrays which I have been playing with so I have been able to generate the alphabet.
What I really want to do is have a word appear with random letters missing and then letters of the alphabet appears and player needs to select correct letter to complete word.

I am not after code, as an educator I am not fond of cheating, just advice on where I could start, what should I be reading about so that I can achieve what I described.

Many thanks in advance for help and advice

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, XNA is a game framework so it helps you make games easy becouse you are using its templates, but for you i think its not necessary, you can look for ready game enginees, like unity.Anyway you can ask here http://gamedev.stackexchange.com good luck

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you're looking for an *algorithm* (or even pseudocode) rather than code or anything else. If I was to implement a game as you described, I would go about it the following fashion:

1. **Select a word from a list.** This "dictionary" could be as simple as a text file containing different words, or a more complex database of all words in the English language.
2. **Pick a letter from the word and remove it.**
3. **Ask the user for the missing letter.** Keep asking until they guess correctly or they run out of guesses.
4. Rise and repeat.

This is a pretty simple game, which uses pretty basic concepts. I believe the XNA would be complete overkill in this situation. Like Mustafa mentioned in the comment on the original post, XNA provides a framework that makes game progamming easier because it provides templates, but it also adds a lot of overhead and needless complexity (especially for a novice programmer.) Since you're coming from a non-programming background, I would suggest Python or Ruby as a good starting language, and suggest looking into the following topics:

- Reading from file (the "dictionary" mentioned above)
- Loops, specifically for-loops and while-loops or the language equivalent (to allow the user to keep guessing until they run out of guesses or guess correctly)
- Command-line input/output (IO) -- print to screen and read input from the console.
- Arrays and Strings

Once you've built out a working command-line application, *then* I would suggest looking into things like Graphical User Interfaces (GUIs) and making it look "pretty."

Comment: Hi Mustafa and Roddy, thank you for your replies, they are both good advice, now I know what to look for and which route to take. I have recently been looking at arrays and will continue, loops sound interesting will look into that next too, thanks both again.